# Blazor: Authentication remains false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I have a middleware in my Startup.cs file which checks the users current authentication state. However, when debugging, it appears that even after a successful login the authentication remains false. I have searched for a solution, many of which provide solutions that not do work or do not apply to my project. I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue or could provide any insight into how I might resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

### Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next.Invoke();

        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var username = context.User.Identity.Name;

            using (var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
            {
                var user = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
                user.LastAccessed = DateTime.Now;
                dbContext.Update(user);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    });
  app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
}
```

### Name remains empty

I feel like it has no idea if someone has logged in since the name does not show either
[image]

Comment: `it appears that even after a successful login the authentication remains false` where exactly? Do you put a breakpoint in your custom middleware, and the `IsAuthenticated` returns `false`?

Comment: @Ergis I have put a breakpoint at `await next.Invoke()` the check performed `if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` is false and so the code below it is skipped

Comment: Can you check the values/claims of `context.User.Identity`? Also this seem to be a problem with your API server, not Blazor.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what OP is expecting but this may come in handy for anyone in the future stumbling upon this question. .NET expects [`ClaimsIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated?view=net-6.0#remarks) to have [`AuthenticationType` property set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.authenticationtype?view=net-6.0) to be considered Authenticated.

> ### ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated
>
> true if the AuthenticationType property is not null or an empty string.

When I made a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`, I had to make sure to set it:

```cs
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {

        public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            string? authType = null;

            // ...
            
            // Without this, it won't be considered authenticated
            authType = "Token";


            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authType);
            var state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
            
            return await Task.FromResult(state);
        }

    }
```

EDIT: I just took a closer look at OP's screenshot. Looks like it's happening to an API server code. I was fooled by the `blazor-webassembly` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseRouting();` like this :

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this did not seem to work for me either.

Comment: app.UseRouting(); should be before UseIdentityServer();

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the picture in your question, made a snippet here:
[image]

That means that Microsoft is looking for the name and role claim that is in the format of a URL, like the picture shows.

To tell Microsoft what the name of your claim is, then you need to add :

```
opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)